# How can I build the java software that I gave at below

Tags: linux, java, arch-linux, compile, build

As a language learner I want to use it so bad but sadly I have no any clue for building. [The Software](https://github.com/tilarids/subkuro) I forgot to mention it, I am using linux currently.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps

1. **Download and install [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads)**
2. **Download and install [IntelliJ Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/)** (you can either use 30-day evaluation period or Community edition)
3. **Open command prompt**, CD to any folder you wish to download the sources to and use the following command `git clone https://github.com/tilarids/subkuro.git`
4. **Start IntelliJ Idea** and open the project from the folder which you just downloaded
5. **Build the project** (you can google further info how to build with IntelliJ Idea